# durablity and brand?

Tags: mountain-bike, identify-this-bike

[image][image] Here's some photos:on the left is the suspension,on the right is the crank set,on the bottom left is the front derailleur and on the bottom right is the back derailleur

I recently spray painted my bike that was given to me by someone, and then, I suddenly got curious to find what is the brand of this bike but i couldn't as it was covered, so any idea what brand it might be?

Also, will it be suitable to ride on rough terrains using it? or parts to upgrade it?

EDIT: After a month of research, I think this is an EVEREST brand mountain bike.is it any good?   And it is steel?

Comment: As regards the brand, I haven't a clue. As regards the safety to ride, I suggest you take it to your local bike shop to see what they say. On the one hand, the bike has full suspension so it might be suited to rough terrain. On the other hand, lots of not-very-good bikes have full suspension to try and make them look good. It's impossible to say from a photograph.

Comment: It's a full-suspension bike, and such bikes are purported to be designed for fairly rugged off-road use.  However, some Chinese makers produce "wannabe" bikes that look tough but are barely suited for city streets, so it's hard to say.

Comment: I'm curious, where do people get all these unidentified bikes? A trivial solution to all these questions would be just asking the seller.

Comment: @ojs I'm curious too. Who goes around giving bikes away to people? Nobody ever gave me a bike.

Comment: @ojs My local bike co-op has tons of old frames and random parts.  They aren't the first owner of the frame, and if the previous owner removed all the decals, it would probably be quite hard to identify them as a particular model. In this case the person said the frame was given to them, why they wouldn't ask the person who gave it to them is beyond me.

Comment: That looks very BSO to me, I'd weigh it and if it's over 10kg it's not safe to ride off road. One of the things lost in the decal stripping was the sticker saying "not for off road use or stunting".

Comment: @Moz I don't think that 10kg  is a good number to go by for a full suspension mountain bike.  [This bike](http://www.devinci.com/bikes/bike_702_scategory_166) is definitely off-road worthy and weighs in at 14.33kg.  With 6.8 KG being the UCI limit for road bikes, I don't think you'll find a lot of mountain bikes below 10kg.

Answer (score 3):

You'd probably get a good information by looking at the components.  Assuming the components are original, you can tell a lot information about the general quality of the frame from the quality components. Almost nobody is putting DuraAce on a cheap Walmart frame, and almost nobody is putting Tourney parts on a Cervello.  The bolt on wheels and ProMax crank lead to me believe that this bike is more likely from Walmart or another department store. That doesn't mean it is, but it could be.  Also, it has V-Brakes, which most quality full suspension bikes don't use any more. They've almost entirely switched over to disk brakes at the high end.  Get some more pictures showing close ups of the derailleurs, crankset, suspension, and the markings on the rim of the wheel to help us evaluate it further.

Comment: If the bike is more than about 5 years old (which is certainly likely) it would be incredibly unusual to find disk brakes on it.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I think you forget how long disk brakes have been in use. Here's a [line up from 2010](http://2010.devinci.com/bikes/category_3) from the only bike manufacturer I know who keeps yearly archives of their website. Every mountain bike they sold had disk brakes.

Comment: I didn't say they didn't exist.  But they were incredibly expensive.

Comment: @DanielRHicks expensive disks are more like 15 years old, not 5. When I built my current commuter about 5 years ago cheap cable disks for widely available and reliable. $1000 disk brakes were definitely available, but $50 cable sets were too.

Comment: @Mσᶎ - Yep, right around 5 years ago disk brake prices dropped rather quickly, when they began to become OE on some midrange models.  And, of course, "expensive" is relative.  I would consider an option that adds $500 to the price of bike to be "expensive".  Others might not.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I'm in the bracket of "will pay more upfront to save money in the long term", hence my Rohloff hub for example. And some things you just can't do cheaply-but-effectively at all, like brakes for a tandem :)

Answer (score 1):

Is it steel?  Can't tell from a photo, so you need to use a magnet.  If a magnet sticks, its steel.

Is it a good bike?  If you want to ride it, enjoy riding it, fit comfortably on it and it doesn't fail under you, then its a good bike.